# How can I exclude empty folders with Asciidoctor maven plugin

Tags: maven, asciidoctor

I use Asciidoctor Maven Plugin for generating HTML from adoc. Unfortunately it copies every source directory from the directory specified in `sourceDirectory`. How can I exclude these empty folders?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
    <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>test-id</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>mysourcedirectory</sourceDirectory>
                <sourceDocumentName>Test.adoc</sourceDocumentName>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/outputdir</outputDirectory>
                <relativeBaseDir>true</relativeBaseDir>
                <preserveDirectories>true</preserveDirectories>
                <backend>html</backend>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My input dir looks like this:

```
 ── mysourcedirectory
    ├── Test.adoc  
    └── subfolder1
        ├── doc1.adoc    
        └── doc2.adoc
```

The output of asciidoc looks like this (`subfolder1` is empty and I want it to be excluded):

```
 ── mysourcedirectory
    ├── Test.adoc  
    └── subfolder1
```

According to the documentation of Asciidoc (https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin#configuration-options), I can do it with `resources` tag. I've tried it this way, but it's not working:

```
<configuration>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`asciidoctor-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin) does not support the removal of empty directories. There is [the issue 144](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin/issues/144) about that, and it is not considered for fixing.

You can work-around that by using the [Antrun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and [delete empty directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5706781/1743880) after Ascii Doctor has ran:

```
<!-- your configuration of Ascii Doctor -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
  <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.3</version>
  <!-- rest of your config -->
</plugin>
<!-- deleting empty directories in output directory of Ascii Doctor -->
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>delete-empty-dirs</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          <delete includeemptydirs="true">
            <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/generated-docs">
              <and>
                <size value="0" />
                <type type="dir" />
              </and>
            </fileset>
          </delete>
        </target>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

To make sure the Antrun Plugin is invoked after Ascii Doctor, you can place its declaration after `asciidoctor-maven-plugin`, and make sure they are bound to the same phase. I used the `generate-resources` in the example above.